# Determining when an inequality holds

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose I have $0 < N - \varepsilon  < q$ where $N$ is some large real number and $\varepsilon$ is much smaller than $N$. Can I conclude that $0 < N - \varepsilon  < N < q$?

Comment: Please accept any useful answers that you have received.  You could see [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer)

Comment: @RossMillikan: when someone has only asked 5 questions, I don't think it's *that* unlikely none of the answers are acceptable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You have $0<N-\epsilon<N<q+\epsilon$, but it is entirely possible that $q$ lies between $N-\epsilon$ and $N$.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a theorem which tells us when something like this is true?

Comment: Trivially, it is true whenever $q>N+\epsilon$, or equivalently whenever $q-N>\epsilon$. I'm really not sure what you're going for here...

Comment: I was wondering if given these arbitrary quantities, we can somehow deduce the second inequality.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would think that.

Comment: Never mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Think about $0 <  100000 - 2 < 99999$ ...